# NVD3 Line Chart X Axis Tick count

Tags: javascript, charts, nvd3.js

How to configure the no of ticks on nvd3 line chart axis.

I know that we can have no of tick count on d3 chart using following

```js
var axis = d3.svg.axis().ticks([NO_of_Tick]).scale(widthscale);
```

How this can be done for nvd3 line chart.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show all your `xAxis` tick values by default try using  :

```
nv.models.multiBarChart().reduceXTicks(false);
```

Or if you want to show only certain tick values on your `xAxis` you could try this:

```
// Assuming your xAxis has 1-10
chart.xAxis.tickValues([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: is there no way to set the specific tick count.

Comment: Not quite sure if its possible, sorry